# ExtJS - undefined index of a record in a combobox

Tags: javascript, extjs

The following code describe the problem:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                      fields: ['Name'],
                      data: [                        
                       {
                          Name: 'Java'
                       },
                       {
                          Name: 'C'
                       },
                       {
                          Name: 'Android'
                       }
                      ]
                     });
    store.insert(0, [Ext.create(store.model, {
           Name: ''
        })]);

    Ext.create('widget.combobox', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            margin: '10',
            width: 500,
            store: store,
            displayField: 'Name',
            valueField: 'Name',
            queryMode: 'local'
            listeners: {
                 beforeselect: function (cbo, rec, idx) {                                                                                    
                      console.log(idx);               
                 }
            }
          });
```

The new data being inserted to the store using 'insert' method doesn't have index in combobox. Every time I click on the blank record, I see the log of idx is 'undefined'. My expectation is '0'. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Good find, that's most probably a bug in Ext. The (undocumented) record index is set in `loadData` and `loadRawData` functions, and it is not updated with inserted records.

Don't rely on this buggy implementation and work around it by using the calculated store index:

```
beforeselect: function (cbo, rec) {
    var idx = cbo.getStore().indexOf(rec);
    console.log(idx);
}
```